# how to get parameters from the URL and pass it as a HashMap key JSF? Environment Glassfish , Java 7 , Icefaces

Tags: java, jsf, hashmap

I need pass a key parameter trought URL like this: 
http://localhost:8080/ProvAt-war/monitor.jsf?&id=77-6
And you show the list based on the parameter received 77-6
I get the parameter through javascript funtion

```
<ui:repeat value="#{provatBean.descargandoHashMap.get(QueryString)}" var="desc" rendered="#{not empty provatBean.descargandoHashMap.get('QueryString')}">
    <h:outputText value="#{desc.descProveedor}"/>
    <h:outputText value="EDI" rendered="#{desc.id_grupo/>
    <h:outputText value=" NO-EDI" rendered="#{desc.id_grupo/>
    <h:outputText value="PERECEDEROS" rendered="#{desc.id_grupo}"/>
</ui:repeat>  

var QueryString = function () {
  var query_string = {};
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        // If first entry with this name
    if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
      query_string[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        // If second entry with this name
    } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
      var arr = [ query_string[pair[0]],decodeURIComponent(pair[1]) ];
      query_string[pair[0]] = arr;
        // If third or later entry with this name
    } else {
      query_string[pair[0]].push(decodeURIComponent(pair[1]));
    }
  } 
  alert(vars[1]);
  return vars[1];  
}();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters of a request are already available via EL via `#{param['key']}`, where `key` is the parameter name of interest. You don't need two dozen lines of JavaScript. And they're already decoded.

This is rather basic.